# How can output result of multi select in Function of Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a function as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_compare_data_extract(tm_id_1 integer,tm_subid_1 integer,tm_id_2 integer,tm_subid_2 integer ) RETURNS integer AS $$


BEGIN
--Select * from A;
--Select * from B;
--Select * from C;

RETURN 0;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

I want output result of 3 query when i run function :
 `SELECT f_compare_data_extract(13,2967,13,2968);`

```
 Select * from A;
 Select * from B;
 Select * from C;
```

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL doesn't support returning multiple result sets from a single command.

If the selects from A, B and C return data in the same format, you can simply UNION ALL them together, to return them as one result set.

If they return data in different formats, you can still UNION ALL them together, but you'll need to add lots of nulls.

Alternatively, have the function create and populate some temporary tables. Then execute the function and select from the temp tables in separate commands.

As a final option, return the data encoded somehow, e.g. using `row_to_json`

Comment: Maybe he should change his return type by SETOF Record first. But you are right. If data are not from the same format it will be complicated but you can tricks using OUT params.